# Create Component every time or track changes on onChanges event?

Tags: angular

I need to have a context-menu in my grid which will be visible on click of any row. I have decided to created it in separate Component and will show it using `ComponentFactoryResolver` and `ViewContainerRef` and destroy it when either click outside this menu or close button.

Now, I was thinking i can do this another way, First i need to create this component on first time user click on any row and when user click close or outside will just hide this menu. On later row clicks component will not created, instead of it will track using `OnChanges` and the value passed to it will reflect and menu will be visible.

With this i need to destroy this menu component on my main component destroy event if i am not wrong. Can any body suggest which way is better or there is another better way to do it.

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. It's difficult to get a clear picture from prosa alone. Just using `*ngFor` might do as well and then add/remove items to/from the array it is bound to.

Answer (score 1):

Its a good idea to have a different component for context-menu. But every time creating a new Component on user click will affect on your application's performance. I just suggest you to have one component and hide/show that component, not create every time.

Also you can change the component's [**ChangeDetectionStrategy**](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/change_detection_strategy_onpush.html) to more improve the performance of you application.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking the same. Will mark this as answer